# Why do the Hero Twins kill Zipacna in the Popol Vuh?

Tags: mythology

I have a very hard time understanding this part of [the story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popol_Vuh). The narrator of the book describes Zipacna favourably. He never does anything villainous.

**So why do the heroes kill him?**

Comment: Is this the work you're asking about? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popol_Vuh

Comment: yes. that book is usually classified as mythology but i find it's structure is much closer to a novel than people would assume. it's definitely not an epic, and it's in prose. i guess the book of genesis is the only other work in the same vein.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I feel it is a much better fit for the [Mythology Stack](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @SQB - Unfortunately this is too old to migrate. Arguably, it's on-topic but only marginally so. Since the OP hasn't been seen in 4 years and since the question has an accepted answer, I'm happy to watch the community bury it if they want to.

Comment: I know it's too old to migrate, but it's off topic nonetheless.

Comment: And Mythology Q & A just went into open Beta, too.

Comment: This post was re-opened when I cleared the migration history from the old literature.se. Closing again.

Answer (score 3):

From [this](http://rd47blog.blogspot.com/2010/09/death-of-zipacna_18.html) reference is this quote:

> What now weighted heavily on the hearts of the two boys was that the
>   Four Hundred Boys had been killed by Zipacna

If this is correct and Zipacna had killed 400 boys, it would be plenty of reason to kill him.

Comment: Yes, but the 400 boys tried to kill Zapacna. He was just defending himself.

Comment: That depends on how you define "defending" yourself. Did he need to kill all 400 to defend himself.

Comment: Good point, but I'm still not convinced. They were pretty cruel to him, plotting his death by throwing him in a pit and smashing him, so it would be fair to say he killed them justly. The best explanation I have yet found is the psychological one. That it represents a transition from the Titans to the Olympians. From the world-crafting gods to the heroic gods, in Greek mythology.

Comment: ...which might be easily enough dismissed. Except that 'A transition from the Titans to the Olympians' is a much better essay title than 'HE NEEDED TO KILL THEM ALL'

Comment: @ShirazBhaiji - The 400 are only ever mentioned as a unit, so it makes sense that they have to all be killed at the same time, mythologically speaking.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the Popol Vuh , you can see this clash coming.  My current favorite translation is the one by Dennis Tedlock (isbn 9780684818450).  Remember that Maya mythology is radically different from Greco-Roman mythology, and fragmented by comparison, so it's a glimpse into a very different kind of world view.

Zipacna was the son of 7-Macaw and the Twins were on a quest to kill all of 7-Macaw's family.  This was because the real gods were displeased that 7-Macaw tricked people into worshiping him as the Sun God.

> page 77- 
>   Being gods, the two of them [i.e. the Twins] saw evil in his [7-Macaw's]
>   attempt at self magnification before Heart of Sky.

Zipacna was as strong as a god and as arrogant as his father, but someone dimwitted.  So the drunken 400 tricked him as a joke, and he got revenge on the 400, and then the Twins got revenge on him.  Symbolically speaking, a drunken prank got out of hand and someone's feelings got hurt.

> page 78-
>   The sons of 7-Macaw are alike and like his they got their greatness
>   [i.e. power and arrogance] from their father.

Additionally The 7-Macaw family was preventing the creation of the Maya people, which obviously would be a great evil in the eyes of the Maya.

> page 77 - And the boys saw evil in this, since our first mother and 
>   father could not yet be made.

And finally, it was fate:

> page 81- What they [the Twins] did was simply the word of Heart of Sky.
>   -footnote pg 284 adds: ...they are carrying out the word of the Sun God
>   while *appearing* to act on their own. [emphasis is mine]

Making the defeat as cruel and humiliating as possible is a common theme in Maya (and almost all mesoamerican) mythologies.  So in that respect the 400 and the Twins were acting more or less appropriately.

It's mentioned in the wiki entry for Zipacna, 7-Macaw, and the twins

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipacna

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_Hero_Twins

(no offense, but i am really surprised this was moved into Sci-Fi/Fantasy out of Mythology)